# What content in “research design”, aside from the fundamentals, should be taught?

Tags: graduate-school, teaching

I’m teaching a course in technical research methods for graduate students. As luck would have it, I have an extra week because a guest lecturer canceled.

Can you think of any content that if not typically taught in a research methods course but would be useful to graduate students?

Ideas:

- helping them make LinkedIn / ResearchGate profiles or something similar
- How to make your thesis into a publication
- Avenues of publication for a thesis (difference between thesis and publication)
- … what else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to ask the guest for any information about what they intended to "cover" an do something like that yourself if you think it has value. They might yield some notes.

But another idea is to make that week into a seminar of sorts in which students discuss possible research plans and you and members of the class comment on them to make them better. If the scale is reasonable then this might be valuable for the students.

If the week consists of several sessions then you might actually invite a colleague to each of them so that they might also comment as part of the seminar. No preparation would be needed so it wouldn't be too hard for another faculty member to participate.

"Teaching" can mean a lot more than delivering material.